# Accessing private API from Lambda Function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, zappa

I need to call a private API say **'/rx/information'** deployed on a server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx from a lambda function deployed using zappa library in python using flask framework. Can anyone suggest the steps required to do so? I tried going through this document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-api-test-invoke-url.html but can't understand it. Thanks for the help !!

Comment: Is your private API deployed on AWS?

Comment: Are you trying to access a resource in a private subnet? It sounds like you need to run your Lambda in a VPC and apply the correct subnets and routing if that is the case.